# Python add space

Tags: python, split

We have the repetitive words like Mr and Mrs in a text. We would like to add a space before and after the keywords Mr and Mrs. But, the word Mr is getting repetitive in Mrs. Please assist in solving the query:

Input:

Hi This is Mr.Sam. Hello, this is MrsPamela.Mr.Sam, what is your call about? Mrs.Pamela, I have a question for you.

```
import re

s = "Hi This is Mr Sam. Hello, this is Mrs.Pamela.Mr.Sam, what is your call about? Mrs. Pamela, I have a question for you."
words = ("Mr", "Mrs")


def add_spaces(string, words):

for word in words:
    # pattern to match any non-space char before the word
    patt1 = re.compile('\S{}'.format(word))

    matches = re.findall(patt1, string)
    for match in matches:
        non_space_char = match[0]
        string = string.replace(match, '{} {}'.format(non_space_char, word))

    # pattern to match any non-space char after the word
    patt2 = re.compile('{}\S'.format(word))
    matches = re.findall(patt2, string)
    for match in matches:
        non_space_char = match[-1]
        string = string.replace(match, '{} {}'.format(word, non_space_char))

return string


print(add_spaces(s, words))
```

**Present Output:**

```
Hi This is Mr .Sam. Hello, this is Mr sPamela. Mr .Sam, what is your call about? Mr s.Pamela, I have a question for you.
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Hi This is Mr .Sam. Hello, this is Mrs Pamela. Mr .Sam, what is your call about? Mrs .Pamela, I have a question for you.
```

Comment: `(\s?Mrs?)\.?(?=[A-Z])` by ` \1.` - https://regex101.com/r/EErqRc/1

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify anything after the letter 'r' so your pattern will match any starting with a space character followed by 'M' and 'r', so this will capture any ' Mr' even if it's followed by a 's' such as Mrs, that's why your your first pattern adds a space in the middle of Mrs.

A better pattern would be `r'\bMr\b'`

`'\b'` captures word boundaries, see the doc for further explanations: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a very extense knowledge of re module, but I came up with a solution which is extendable to any number of words and string and that perfectly works (tested in python3), although it is probably a very extense one and you may find something more optimized and much more concise.
On the other hand, it is not very difficult to understand the procedure:

1. To begin with, the program orders the words list from descending
   length.
2. Then, it finds the matches of the longer words first and takes note
   of the sections where the matches were already done in order not to
   change them again. (Note that this introduces a limitation, but it
   is necessary, due to the program cannot know if you want to allow
   that a word in the variable word can be contained in other, anyway
   it does not affect you case)
3. When it has taken note of all matches (in a non-blocked part of the
   string) of a word, it adds the corresponding spaces and corrects the
   blocked indexes (they have moved due to the insertion of the spaces)
4. Finally, it does a trim to eliminate multiple spaces

Note: I used a list for the variable words instead of a tuple

```
import re

def add_spaces(string, words):
    # Get the lenght of the longest word
    max_lenght = 0
    for word in words:
        if len(word)>max_lenght:
            max_lenght = len(word)
    print("max_lenght = ", max_lenght)

    # Order words in descending lenght
    ordered_words = []
    i = max_lenght
    while i>0:
        for word in words:
            if len(word)==i:
                ordered_words.append(word)
        i -= 1
    print("ordered_words = ", ordered_words)

    # Iterate over words adding spaces with each match and "blocking" the match section so not to modify it again
    blocked_sections=[]
    for word in ordered_words:
        matches = [match.start() for match in re.finditer(word, string)]
        print("matches of ", word, " are: ", matches)

        spaces_position_to_add = []
        for match in matches:
            blocked = False
            for blocked_section in blocked_sections:
                if match>=blocked_section[0] and match<=blocked_section[1]:
                    blocked = True
            if not blocked:
                # Block section and store position to modify after
                blocked_sections.append([match,match+len(word)])
                spaces_position_to_add.append([match,match+len(word)+1])

        # Add the spaces and update the existing blocked_sections
        spaces_added = 0
        for new_space in spaces_position_to_add:
            # Add space before and after the word
            string = string[:new_space[0]+spaces_added]+" "+string[new_space[0]+spaces_added:]
            spaces_added += 1
            string = string[:new_space[1]+spaces_added]+" "+string[new_space[1]+spaces_added:]
            spaces_added += 1

            # Update existing blocked_sections
            for blocked_section in blocked_sections:
                if new_space[0]<blocked_section[0]:
                    blocked_section[0] += 2
                    blocked_section[1] += 2

    # Trim extra spaces
    string = re.sub(' +', ' ', string)

    return string


###  MAIN  ###
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = "Hi This is Mr Sam. Hello, this is Mrs.Pamela.Mr.Sam, what is your call about? Mrs. Pamela, I have a question for you."
    words = ["Mr", "Mrs"]

    print(s)
    print(add_spaces(s,words))
```